# odbc sql statement

Tags: php, sql, odbc

could anybody tell me whats wrong about this statement?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO FK_Kunde(Anschrift_Vorname) VALUES('".$_POST['vorname']."') WHERE Anschrift_Vorname = 'Petra'";
```

errmsg:

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntaxfehler bei 'WHERE' in Zeile 1, SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\php2lex\write2Odbc.php on line 16
shit happens [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntaxfehler bei 'WHERE' in Zeile 1
```

Comment: Anyway, you should protect your `$_POST['vorname']` before insertion or update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Syntax like insert into ... values ... where -
Think you need an update statement.

```
$sql = "Update FK_Kunde set Anschrift_Vorname = '".$_POST['vorname']."' WHERE Anschrift_Vorname = 'Petra'";
```

Also you should lears about prepared statements to protact against SQL injection.